# What data will zk-SNARKs protect?

Tags: security, privacy, zero-knowledge, zksnark

Implementing zk-SNARKs is [planned in Ethereum](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/01/15/privacy-on-the-blockchain/) roadmap, what data will be obfuscated?

1. transaction sender and receiver?
2. data in transactions?
3. data stored in contracts?
4. variables and methods in contracts?

Comment: any updates on this topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no final plans. Initially they might only be used ephemerally for transaction voting to prevent censoring votes. Parts of the transaction would be hidden until the transaction is processed and committed but the final result would still be publicly known (sender, receiver, value). Native support for transactions and contract execution is still to be determined.