# Who can access private state variables?

Tags: contract-design, privacy

I was reading solidity [Docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html) and everything made sense until I got to this:

[image]

What are **external observers**? Is it clients listening for events or is it anyone who has access to web3 api?

For example, who can access and modify **uint private x = 255;** except the contract it's in?

In other words, how can one get the value stored in a private state variable?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/solidity-functions-visibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

External observers are anyone who access to a block explorer, or is otherwise able to get blocks from the network and parse the data on the blockchain.

Note that they can only *access* data in your contract, they are not able to *modify* it.

So we can all find out the value of your uint private x. If I wrote a contract, the contract wouldn't directly be able to see what x was, because x would be a private variable in a different contract. But if my contract trusted me I could look up x myself and send it to my contract as a parameter...

Comment: thank you, I get it now. However, I just looked up the contract account of Eth foundation on etherchain.org and didn't find any information on its state variables. https://etherchain.org/account/0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae#txsent.

Comment: The same on etherscan.io...

Comment: Try https://live.ether.camp/

Comment: just to be clear, there's absolutely no way to call a private function from outside the contract it resides in?

Comment: Correct. A private function can only be called by the contract that declares it.