# Accessibility of public variables

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, security, privacy

If I have a `public` state variable, does this mean that other contracts can access or even change its value?

I have made a cryptocoin from [here](https://www.ethereum.org/token#improved-coin) and all variables are declared as `public`, so I am concerned if other contracts can only view these variables or can they change the values too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `public` state variable will have an automatically generated accessor that other contracts can use to read the variable.

However, public state variables can only be changed by a function in a contract that changes the variable.  If there are no such functions that are accessible to other contracts, the state variable cannot be changed by other contracts.

[Functions can be specified](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#visibility-and-accessors) as being `external`, `public`, `internal` or `private`, where the default is `public`.

> **external**: External functions are part of the contract interface, which
>   means they can be called from other contracts and via transactions. An
>   external function f cannot be called internally (i.e. `f()` does not
>   work, but `this.f()` works). External functions are sometimes more
>   efficient when they receive large arrays of data.
>
> **public**: Public functions are part of the contract interface and can be
>   either called internally or via messages. For public state variables,
>   an automatic accessor function (see below) is generated.
>
> **internal**: Those functions and state variables can only be accessed
>   internally (i.e. from within the current contract or contracts
>   deriving from it), without using `this`.
>
> **private**: Private functions and state variables are only visible for
>   the contract they are defined in and not in derived contracts.