# Solidity - Can an attacker call private functions?

Tags: solidity, security

Looking around I found [Solidity functions - private visibility](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/solidity-functions-private-visibility) but not an answer to my specific question. Basically my question is: is the `private` keyword enforced at the Solidity language level or EVM level? My intuition says it is a Solidity feature but I wanted to double check here.

I am just getting started with Ethereum so pardon any beginner mistakes. Consider the following Solidity code:

```
contract Silly {
  function unsafePrivateWithdraw(address addr, uint amount) private {
    addr.transfer(amount);
  }
  function safeWithdraw(address addr, uint amount) {
    if (!checkWithdrawConditions) throw; // pseudocode
    unsafePrivateWithdraw(addr, amount);
  }
}
```

I know that using Solidity one wouldn't be able to call `unsafePrivateWithdraw` directly. But could somebody write in LLL or EVM opcodes a direct call to the address of the `unsafePrivateWithdraw` function?

Answer (score 15):

No.

A `private` or `internal` function can only be called by the contract itself. Further, `private` functions cannot be called by derived contracts--so `internal` is more common. [Here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) is Solidity's own documentation on the subject.

How does the EVM enforce this? Simple. On the EVM level, *there are no function calls*. Rather, Solidity generates a dispatcher for each contract, and sending a transaction just activates said dispatcher. On a theoretical level, making a function private is just a matter of *not* putting it in the dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks! That helps some, I see now that a private function (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/v0.4.11/libsolidity/codegen/ExpressionCompiler.cpp#L532) uses a JUMP instruction but a non-private function would use a CALL-series instruction (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/v0.4.11/libsolidity/codegen/ExpressionCompiler.cpp#L1718).

I am still lacking a bit of clarity though. What does it mean to add a function to a dispatcher? Does that involve calling JUMPDEST?

Comment: Is it possible to call a private/internal function from the web3js frontend?

Comment: @Ruham: No. There's no way to call a private/internal function in any way except from the contract itself. The web3js frontend only sends transactions, or simulates them being called.