# Is it possible to fake contract owner address?

Tags: solidity, security

this link talks about contract visibility and accessibility in the blockchain. 
[Solidity functions - private visibility](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/solidity-functions-private-visibility)

So if I use the keyword "onlyOwner" only the owner can call the function?

Is it possibile to fake the sending address of the owner or the blockchain nature already prevents it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onlyOwner` is defined in the contract code. The code checks that `msg.sender` matches the `owner` variable that has been set previously.

`msg.sender` is created automatically: It's either the account that signed the transaction or the contract that called your contract. You can rely on it to be correct and not faked: If you could fake `msg.sender`, Ethereum would be completely broken.

The owner address will depend on the previous code that defines it, but it will be correct unless that code is buggy.