# Will forthcoming ability to make transactions private hide gas usage and mining information?

Tags: transactions, blocks, privacy, anonymity, zksnark

I understand that people are working on allowing for more private transactions on the public Ethereum mainnet.

This would involve hiding (at the very least) the `from`, `to`, `value` and probably `input` fields, but I wonder what other information will be hidden, such as gasUsed, gasPrice, winning miner, mining reward, etc.

I, for one, would suggest that this information not be hidden so that broad, chain-wide information can be collected and analyzed.

What parts of a block and/or transaction data be hidden when we can do more private transactions?

Comment: "_I understand that people are working on allowing for more private transactions on the public Ethereum mainnet._" Do you have any sources for this? I'm interested in knowing more. :)

Comment: Not really. I just remember when zcash came out a lot of people (including I think Vitalik who may have published something) were talking about enabling zk-snarks on Ethereum. Sorry, I don't have a reference.

Comment: Aha - https://z.cash/blog/zksnarks-in-ethereum.html, and https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/12/05/zksnarks-in-a-nutshell/

Comment: zksnarks will make anonymous transfers possible, but obfuscated computation, which would be necessary to hide the transaction input, isn't on the horizon.

Comment: What constitutes hiding the transaction input vs anonymous transfer? Do you mean the `input` data of a transaction?  And, does an anonymous transfer mean that the `from` and `to` fields are hidden in some way?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/what-data-will-zk-snarks-protect