# Is there any way to hide a transaction?

Tags: privacy, anonymity, zksnark, ring-signatures

Is there any way to hide a transaction on the Ethereum blockchain?

Some blockchain have protocols that implement this by default, like Monero and Zcash. Is something similar possible on Ethereum?

Comment: This question is focused on the "user".  For a focus on "contracts" see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/private-info-on-ethereum

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/what-data-will-zk-snarks-protect

Answer (score 11):

No.

All information on the blockchain is visible to all participants.

Having said that, some clever uses of encrypted data exist for specific use cases. zkSnarks may provide general-purpose obfuscation in the future.

Answer (score 5):

There's ring mixing contract with source code [here](https://github.com/blackyblack/laundromat) which has similar (in fact, flipped) properties to Monero's ring signature mixes.

It offers anonymity to *recipients* rather than senders, meaning that if you use it to make payments (as in, you deposit a public key and the intended recipient has the corresponding private key with which to withdraw), even **you**, the sender, cannot determine which of the withdrawal addresses corresponds to your recipient (cool right)

Answer (score 4):

Sort of.

There's some work going to get zCash running on ethereum here: https://z.cash/blog/zksnarks-in-ethereum.html.

It seems like the ideas is: you would probably have an initial, traceable contract; but others can then use this to preform untraceable transactions with it.

Comment: Is it possible to swap Eth with zCash then swap it back and send the Eth to a new wallet?

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo, why wouldn't it be?