# In ethereum if i submit any data is it stored in encrypted format?

Tags: blockchain, encryption

Does Blockchain perform encryption/decryption of data?How and where is data stored in ethereum case.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in encryption in Ethereum. In fact, Ethereum is really bad for all privacy purposes. You can find a lot of information with Google, here's one post about it: [Anonymity and Privacy on Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12631/anonymity-and-privacy-on-ethereum)

The data is stored in the blockchain and is publicly available for all nodes.